# Retrieve mapping data from one contract to another contract in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Here, I'm trying to get `tempMap` data from `MainContract` in `Temp` contract but I'm not able to get value form `tempMap`, as well as I'm using `external` visibility in MainContract but still didn’t get any response.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract MainContract {
    mapping(uint => string) public tempMap;

    function addData(uint number,string memory name ) public {
        tempMap[number] = name;
    }

    function get(uint number) external view returns(string memory){
        return tempMap[number];
    }
}

contract Temp{
    MainContract main = new MainContract();

    function getData(uint number) public view returns(string memory){
        return main.get(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the address of the deployed contract, so it knows where to make the call.

Your temp contract will look something like this.

```
contract Temp{

    MainContract main;

    constructor(MainContract _main) {
        main = _main;
    }
    

    function getData(uint number) public view returns(string memory){
        return main.get(number);
    }
}
```